# Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade php 5.4 missing php5-ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I updated php to version 5.4 but now I can not install the package php5-ffmpeg because it gives me this error:
php5-ffmpeg: Depends: phpapi-20090626

also if I try to write php-v gives me this warning:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/usr/lib/php5/20100525/ffmpeg.so' - / usr/lib/php5/20100525/ffmpeg.so:
can not open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
5.4.17RC1 PHP (cli) (built: Jun 22 2013 19:27:26)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Some solution?

Comment: how did you upgrade? compile yourself? you can't mix/match php packages from different versions of PHP. the internal APIs differ and modules from one version are generally totally useless in another.

Comment: I have not compiled but I used the appropriate repository to update the version.
No mix of versions.
The problem is that I can not use php5-ffmpeg.

Comment: phpapi-__20090626__ vs __20100525__
They are different versions of the API, therefore it will not work.
What OS are you running? Version? What repositories are you using? What was your original PHP version? Is php5-ffmpeg being supplied by the new repository you used for PHP 5.4? (If not, that is almost definitely your issue.)